# Duplicate multiple class value get inside the DIV

Tags: php, dom

I have a html part to retrieve through simple domparser.

This is my HTML code.

```
<div class="descriptio">
    <div class="sptr"><h4>Directors</h4><a href="">Jhon 1</a>, <a href="">Jhon 2</a>, <a href="">Jhon 3</a></div>
    <div class="sptr"><h4>Writers</h4><a href="">Doe 1</a>, <a href="">Doe 2</a>, <a href="">Doe 3</a></div>
    <div class="sptr"><h4>Stars</h4><a href="">Ann 1</a>, <a href="">Ann 2</a>, <a href="">Ann 3</a></div>
</div>
```

I want to get "descriptio" class value differently inside the "sptr" class.
what I exactly want to retrieve.

Directors : Jhon 1, Jhon 2, Jhon 3

Writers : Doe 1, Doe 2, Doe 3

Stars : Ann 1, Ann 2, Ann 3

I tried with this code, but it is wrong

```
<?PHP 
    $directors = '';
    foreach ($html_page_url->find('div.description div.sptr') as $val) 
    {
        $directors.= $val.',';
    } 
?>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Create array and use implode

Comment: but it will come all the values per one line, I want to insert director values to 1 column in database like Writers and stars to different column

Answer (score 0):

Use DOMDocument and DomXPath:

```
<?php 


$html = '<div class="descriptio">
    <div class="sptr"><h4>Directors</h4><a href="">Jhon 1</a>, <a href="">Jhon 2</a>, <a href="">Jhon 3</a></div>
    <div class="sptr"><h4>Writers</h4><a href="">Doe 1</a>, <a href="">Doe 2</a>, <a href="">Doe 3</a></div>
    <div class="sptr"><h4>Stars</h4><a href="">Ann 1</a>, <a href="">Ann 2</a>, <a href="">Ann 3</a></div>
</div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($html);
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$classname="descriptio";
$divDescriptio = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");

$i = 0;
$row = [];

foreach ($divDescriptio[0]->getElementsByTagName('div') as $element) 
{
    $row[$i]['title'] = $element->getElementsByTagName('h4')[0]->nodeValue;
    $names = $element->getElementsByTagName('a');

    foreach($names as $name)
    {
        $row[$i][] = $name->nodeValue;
    }

    $i++;
}   


var_dump($row);
?>
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Directors"
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Jhon 1"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Jhon 2"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "Jhon 3"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "Writers"
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Doe 1"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Doe 2"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "Doe 3"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "Stars"
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Ann 1"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Ann 2"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "Ann 3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this.

Comment: If it helps you, you could mark as answer/upvote to help other people.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep them in 3 different variables you can do this:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div class="descriptio">
    <div class="sptr"><h4>Directors</h4><a href="">Jhon 1</a>, <a href="">Jhon 2</a>, <a href="">Jhon 3</a></div>
    <div class="sptr"><h4>Writers</h4><a href="">Doe 1</a>, <a href="">Doe 2</a>, <a href="">Doe 3</a></div>
    <div class="sptr"><h4>Stars</h4><a href="">Ann 1</a>, <a href="">Ann 2</a>, <a href="">Ann 3</a></div>
</div>
HTML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// Retrieve each category
$headers = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h4');

foreach ($headers as $header) {
    // This will hold the name of each variable
    $category = strtolower($header->nodeValue);

    // This will become $directors, $writers or $stars
    $$category = "{$header->nodeValue}: ";

    // Retrieve the links of each category
    $links = $header->parentNode->getElementsByTagName('a');

    $temp = array();
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        $temp[] = $link->nodeValue;
    }

    $$category .= implode(',', $temp);
}

echo "{$directors}\n{$writers}\n{$stars}";
```

Output:

```
Directors: Jhon 1,Jhon 2,Jhon 3
Writers: Doe 1,Doe 2,Doe 3
Stars: Ann 1,Ann 2,Ann 3
```